# Is it possible to get outlook Inspector.CurrentItem (MailItem) file path, which was opened from file explorer?

Tags: c#, outlook, office-interop, mailitem

I have such code where I get an email from the active outlook inspector:

```
var app = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application();
var inspector = app.ActiveInspector();

if(inspector?.CurrentItem is MailItem) {
    MailItem mailItem = inspector.CurrentItem;
}
```

Email was opened from windows desktop.
Is it possible to get file path, where is this email physically located?

Comment: This feels like a XY Problem - https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem . _Why_ are you trying to do this?

Comment: @mjwills, I need to save opened msg file with his actual FileName. Now I have workaround: I SaveAs a mailItem and use his subject for FileName. This is suitable for cases when mail was opened from outlook explorer, but there are specific business requirements for existing emails in the file system. Thanks for the link, it is interesting topic :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, because once it's loaded it's no different than any other `Mailitem` that wasn't loaded from the file system, i.e. one that you opened from an explorer window.